# Create two functions to counts object properties/methods

Tags: javascript

```
Object.size = function(obj){
var size = 0, key = "";
   for(key in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        size++;
      }
   }
  return size;
}
```

This is the first function that I created. The mission is to create two functions, one counts properties only and the other one counts properties and methods. (Limit the counting to the original objec, also I need to add the functions to the Object prototype so that each object I create has the two functions available automatically as a property.)

So how do I do the second function? (And could you please take a look at my first one and see if I did anything wrong in my first function?)
Thank you very much!

Comment: So much easier to do `return Object.keys(obj).length`

Comment: "Methods" are properties too, the property values just happen to be functions. With this in mind, the phrase "counts properties and methods" doesn't make much sense. Maybe you want the first function to count only properties that are not functions?

Comment: I don't know either. Since I was asked to count the methods in the object, I have no idea how to find and count the methods of an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of properties and methods:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Number of properties:

```
#test used by underscore.js
function isMethod(obj, func) {
    return !!(obj.func && obj.func.constructor && obj.func.call && obj.func.apply);
}

function num_properties(obj){   
    var size = 0;
    for(key in obj){
        if (!isMethod(obj, key)){
            size++;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit about how does "function isMethod" do? Is this function aimed to exclude the counting for methods?

Comment: Sure, I can try.  
As you guessed, the isMethod function checks to see whether or not a given obj has a given function.  I does this by checking several things.  

First, it checks whether or not the key exists in the obj.
Then it check whether the key has a call param (a characteristic of functions).  And finally, it checks whether obj.key has a apply param, a second characteristic of javascript functions.

Finally, the !! operator simply casts the contents of the parens to boolean.  It's kind of a hack, but it's fairly widely used hack.  It ensures a boolean is returned.

Comment: No problem.  Just let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array of an object's[#properties, #methods, #properties that are not methods],
or return just the index you want-

```
Object.size= function size(obj){
    var props= 0, methods= 0, key;
    for(key in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(typeof obj[key]== 'function')++methods;
            ++props;
        }
    }
    return [props, methods, props-methods];
}
```

Comment: Is that actually "props-methods" or "props+methods"? Thank you!

Comment: The third index is the number of all owned properties (props) minus those that are functions (methods).